# NodeJS Json file keeps rolling back

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I made a discord bot in node that stores the number of messages a person sent in a json file.
As there are only around 20 people on the discord, I feel like using a database isn't necessary.
However, it appears that when the website I use for the hosting (I tried repl.it and Heroku) has a moment of lag, the json rolls back to an older version. It does that very often and I can't find out the reason for it.

Here is how I write the data:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const userDataFile = require('./userdata.json');

var currGuild;
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Connected as ' + client.user.tag);
  currGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('*********438818862'); //this is the discord server my bot is used on
});

client.on('message', receivedMessage => {
  if (receivedMessage.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name == 'Bot')) {
    return;
  }
  addScore(receivedMessage);
});

function addScore(receivedMessage){
  if (!userDataFile[receivedMessage.author.id]){
    userDataFile[receivedMessage.author.id] = {
      messageCount: 1,
      mult: 1,
      multTimer: 0
    };
  }
  else{
    userDataFile[receivedMessage.author.id].messageCount =
      userDataFile[receivedMessage.author.id].messageCount +
      userDataFile[receivedMessage.author.id].mult;
  }
  try {
    fs.writeFile('./userdata.json', JSON.stringify(userDataFile, null, 2), function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err); //this error never pops up, implying that the file is always written properly
  }
  console.log('Message received');
}

client.login('***********************************************************');
```

Here is the json file:

```
{
  "********9657277454": {
    "messageCount": 38,
    "mult": 1,
    "multTimer": 0
  },
  "********2295954465": {
    "messageCount": 3,
    "mult": 1,
    "multTimer": 0
  },
  "********5595918339": {
    "messageCount": 60,
    "mult": 1,
    "multTimer": 0
  },
  "********9101358080": {
    "messageCount": 3,
    "mult": 1,
    "multTimer": 0
  },
  "********1601591296": {
    "messageCount": 3,
    "mult": 1,
    "multTimer": 0
  },
  "********2859962381": {
    "messageCount": 1,
    "mult": 1,
    "multTimer": 0
  }
}
```

There are other functions that modify this file, to update multTimer as well as mult. I'm not showing these to avoid making the code too long. The multTimer is simply updated every minute and removes 1 to every person if their value is above 0. Mult is updated when the person wins a random minigame in the chat.

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help!

Comment: You're requiring userDataFile. I.e. loading its contents once only. If you update that, any existing instances of this code will be looking at whatever they loaded when they started up. I don't know anything about Discord, but I suspect this bot would be long lived and have multiple workers to serve more than one request at a time.

Comment: I suspect it would have worked if you'd used a database or other shared resource that is used by all workers with strong consistency guarantees.

Comment: I don't know about the multiple instances, but that's something I suspected. I'm going to try requiring after I write to it.

Comment: I know but I'm a beginner so I thought using a json file would be simpler

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html will help you learn how to load the json file without require. You'll have to load it on every request. As you are writing it as well, you may run into race conditions. E.g. worker1 reads file, worker 2 reads file, worker1 updates file, worker2 updates file. As worker2 read the file before worker1 updated it, when it writes it back out, it would overwrite worker1s changes. So you might need a mutex which will effectively mean only 1 worker at a time is able to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I fixed it.

Instead of accessing the json file with
`require('./userdata.json');`, I read it every time I need to write to it like this:

```
let rawUserDataFile = fs.readFileSync('./userdata.json');
var userDataFile = JSON.parse(rawUserDataFile);
```

Then I simply write the same way I did earlier:

```
fs.writeFile('./userdata.json', JSON.stringify(userDataFile, null, 2), function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

This is working so far, but only time will tell if it still rolls back or not (It shouldn't)

I think the error was caused by the fact that sometimes, when the file would be written somewhere in the code, it would write what it read on startup and "forget" the edits I did to it. I don't really know how that happens, but it seems to be the issue.

Comment: Put a long delay in-between reading and writing and then make several concurrent requests and you will start to see the behaviour I describe in my comment. Just something to be aware of.